# Qual a diferença entre "~/" e "../" para navegação de diretorios?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu vi isto em algum lugar, queria saber qual a diferença.

Comment: Você está se referindo a um sistema *NIX? Ou é outra coisa? O único `~` que eu conheço se refere à pasta *home* do usuário nesses sistemas, e a mesma convenção não é usada no Windows (que eu saiba). Outros sistemas podem ter convenções diferentes (li num comentário abaixo que o asp.net usa o `~/` para denominar a raiz da aplicação). Por outro lado, o `..` é mais ou menos padronizado em todo lugar, então não tem dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi, vamos lá, o `/` referencia a raiz do diretório do SO (arquitetura Unix, no caso, via console), apenas o `/` acessa a raiz do seu projeto, e, `../` o nível acima, veja esse exemplo prático:

Imagine que você está criando uma aplicação web e possui a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

```
css
    style.css
    reset.css
images
    logo.png
    sprite.png
javascript
    main.js
    jquery.js
index.htm
about.htm
```

Agora você deseja formatar a classe "logotipo", onde, tal classe terá como imagem de fundo o arquivo `logo.png` (que está na pasta `images`). Tal classe fará parte do arquivo style.css, ficaria assim:

```
.logotipo {
        background: url('../images/logo.png');
}
```

Para finalizar, o arquivo `style.css` está na pasta `css`, e, para acessar a pasta `images` é necessário voltar um nível (por isso usamos '../'), e, após isso acessar a pasta com o logotipo, ficou claro?

Espero ter ajudado, abraços.

Comment: A valeu essa de ../ eu já sabia, só queria saber o ~/ e essa parte não ficou claro.... Seria a raiz do servidor?

Comment: A, acho que entendi. valeu então!!!!....

Comment: Você teria alguma referência para nós consultarmos? Sempre entendi que `/` era a raiz do servidor, e `~` a pasta home do usuário. `.` a pasta corrente (i.e. a própria pasta) e `..` a pasta logo acima (a pasta mãe). Mas claro, tecnologias diferentes podem ter convenções diferentes, daí a confusão (e a necessidade de uma referência confiável, para embasar melhor a resposta).

Comment: Sim @mgibsonbr, acabei me confundindo, obrigado!